# Counter increment with websocket using python

Tags: python, websocket

Wondering if anyone can help. I'm trying to grab data from a websocket and put it into a DataFrame and count how many times I received a response. I feel like it would be easier to count before and send the data after but my code isn't working.

```
import websocket
import json

this = json.dumps({'op': 'subscribe', 'channel': 'trades', 'market': 'BTC-PERP'})

def on_open(wsapp):
   wsapp.send(this)

def on_message(wsapp, message):
    #print(message)
    count = 0
    for messages in message:

        count = count + 1
        print(count)



wsapp = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://ftx.com/ws/", on_message=on_message,
on_open=on_open)
wsapp.run_forever()
```

I will create the dataframe with the websocket data and the counter by appending them. is this a good idea ?

and here an example of what I want to do :
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krP9d.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`on_message` is called every time a message arrives, so the `message` parameter is equal to a single message.
By iterating over that message in `for messages in message:` you are iterating over characters of the message string, and counting each character.

One solution is to use a class to keep track of the message count:

```
import websocket
import json

this = json.dumps({'op': 'subscribe', 'channel': 'trades', 'market': 'BTC-PERP'})

def on_open(wsapp):
    wsapp.send(this)

class Counter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

    def on_message(self, wsapp, message):
        #print(message)

        self.count += 1
        print(self.count)

counter = Counter()

wsapp = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://ftx.com/ws/", on_message=counter.on_message,
on_open=on_open)
wsapp.run_forever()
```

Or you could use `WebSocket` instead of `WebSocketApp` and iterate over the messages similarly to your existing code:

```
import websocket
import json

this = json.dumps({'op': 'subscribe', 'channel': 'trades', 'market': 'BTC-PERP'})

ws = websocket.WebSocket()
ws.connect("wss://ftx.com/ws/")
# from on_open
ws.send(this)
# from on_message
count = 0

for message in ws:
    # print(message)
    count += 1
    print(count)
ws.close()
```

I'll leave the `DataFrame` manipulation to you, since that is a separate issue.

Comment: thank you, I understand. 
The second example does work but the first doesn't print anything. 
Anyway thanks again !